# jQuery unexpected refresh of page when submit an AJAX form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, page-refresh

I have a problem, with AJAX submit of forms.

I have a piece of code like that:

```
$("#content").html("<form id='requestInfo'>............</form");
```

That put in a div with *id=content* the piece of code that creates a form.

I have another piece of code:

```
$("#requestInfo").submit(function( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  ...code...
});
```

I would expect an execution of the code inside the submit() method where I can do my things with data of that form, but I get a refresh of the page, instead.

Does anyone know what could be the problem? It should be compatible with all browsers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating your form dynamically thus standard event binding will not work. You need to use event delegation

```
$("#content").on('submit', '#requestInfo', function(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to call e.preventDefault(); and return false

```
$("#requestInfo").submit(function( event ) {
    // Code here
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
});
```